# JS zooming framework (google maps style)

Tags: frameworks, javascript, zui

I'd like to build a web app based on a zooming principle (ZUI)
I'm looking for a framework or a starting point.
something like OpenZoom http://openzoom.org/
but in javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found this one http://concentriclivers.com/slippymap.html

Answer (score 0):

How about using a jQuery plugin?

http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jquery-fancyzoom/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for.
I'm thinking more at something like google maps zoom-pan engine